# Dispatching two async action in the resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to dispatch two actions inside the resolver:

award.resolver.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AwardResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromAwards.State>
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const { kind } = route.params; 
    const { period } = route.queryParams;
    
    this.store.dispatch(
      AwardsActions.fetchAwards({ kind: 'shops', period })
    );
    this.store.dispatch(
      AwardsActions.fetchAwards({ kind: 'areas', period })
    );

    return of();
  }
}
```

Each actions is intercepted by an effect which trigger an API call. However the first API call is somehow cancelled and i can't understand why.

I will add the effect code for completeness:

award.effect.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AwardsEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private service: NpsService) {}

  fetchAwards$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AwardsActions.fetchAwards),
      switchMap(({ kind, period }) => {
        return this.service.getAwards(period, kind).pipe(
          map((awards) => AwardsActions.awardsSuccess({ kind, awards })),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
            of(AwardsActions.awardsError({ kind, error: error.message }))
          )
        );
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Where `this.service.getAwards(period, kind)` is a simple `http.get`.

DevTool:

[image]

Network tab inside console:

[image]

Comment: That's because you use `switchMap` in your effect, that cancels the previous stream each time new arrives. Switching to `concatMap` may help, but basically your setup is wrong. You should have one action, that corresponds to the request in the service. So it would be better to have `fetchShopAwards` and `fetchAreasAwards`

Comment: `concatMap` fixed my problem. Can I ask you why is a bad practice to put both requests in the same effect?

Comment: https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/avoid-dispatching-multiple-actions-sequentially.md

Comment: Thank you @timdeschryver , but here i need the API call to be executed in this specific order. How can I ensure that?

Comment: @NicolaScionti it's a bad practise because you will end up having "if" logic in your reducer. Basically, you should never group something, that serves different purposes. In your example your are fetching different types of data, so it should be done apart